# Symfony4 Twig template error: Variable "widget" does not exist

Tags: symfony, twig

I am getting Twig_Error_Runtime
[image]

I am trying to find the mistake I've made, but I can't see any... maybe I am looking at the wrong file, but I've tried looking everywhere I've done changes before this error appeared.

This is my twig code:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    <div class="container">

        {% form_theme form 'bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig' %}
        {{ form_start(form) }}

        <br>

        Name {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
        Price {{ form_widget(form.price) }}
        Available {{ form_widget(form.available) }}
        Date {{ form_widget(form.date) }}
        <div class="row js-ticket-time-wrapper"
             data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.times.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}"
             data-index="{{ form.times|length }}">
            {% for time in form.times %}
                <div class="col-xs-4 js-ticket-time-item">
                    <a href="#" class="js-remove-time pull-right">
                        <span class="fa fa-close"></span>
                    </a>
                    {{ form_row(time.name) }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <a href="#" class="js-ticket-time-add">
                <span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span>
                Add another Time
            </a>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" formnovalidate>Save</button>
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
{% block js %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var $wrapper = $('.js-ticket-time-wrapper');
            $wrapper.on('click', '.js-remove-time', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).closest('.js-ticket-time-item')
                    .fadeOut()
                    .remove();
            });
            $wrapper.on('click', '.js-ticket-time-add', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
                var prototype = $wrapper.data('prototype');
                // get the new index
                var index = $wrapper.data('index');
                // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
                // instead be a number based on how many items we have
                var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);
                // increase the index with one for the next item
                $wrapper.data('index', index + 1);
                // Display the form in the page before the "new" link
                $(this).before(newForm);
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

I've also made changes in Entities Time & Ticket, but I don't think so this is connected somehow.

Here's my TicketType Form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name',TextType::class)
        ->add('price',MoneyType::class)
        ->add('available',IntegerType::class)
        ->add('date',DateType::class)
        ->add('times', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => \App\Form\TimeType::class,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'allow_add' => true,
    ));
}
```

And this is TimeType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name', TextType::class);
}
```

Comment: Why not `'entry_type' => TextType::class,` directly? note that `TimeType` will use `block time_widget` by default which is a built-in type. By changing the name of the type `MyTimeType` or overriding the block name should fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the classname of your formtype `TimeType` is the same as the Symfony TimeType (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/time.html) the formtheme layout tries to render the symfony type instead of yours. You can see the symfony `TimeType` has an option called `widget` so the formtype is expecting this type.

So try to rename your `TimeType` to something else like `TicketTimeType`.

Or you can rename your block prefix like this in your `TimeType`:

```
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return "ticket_time_type";
}
```